# What is the difference between these two notations

Tags: java, generics

i am learning generics.

What is the difference between these two notations?

```
public class A<Key extends Comparable<? extends Key>>

public class A<Key extends Comparable<? super Key>>
```

I understand difference between extend and super wildcard generics, but what does it means when used with comparable?

Comment: Second one makes no sense

Comment: @PeterRader, it's the first one that makes no sense...you always want `Comparator<? super Whatever>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman `super` means that even Object is allowed but something inherit from `Key` is not allowed. Why do you think `super` make sense?

Comment: It makes sense for `Comparable`, but not necessarily other types.  `Comparable<Whatever>` means the type is comparable to Whatevers.  `Foo extends Comparable<SubFoo>` is useless, because you can't even compare `Foo` to other `Foo`s, but `SubFoo extends Comparable<Foo>` means you can compare a `SubFoo` to not just other `SubFoo`s, but `Foo`s as well.  `Foo extends Comparable<Object>` means a `Foo` can be compared to anything.

Comment: That's why, for example, [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) has the constraint `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.  If you tried to write it the other way it couldn't work.